# Is there any method to convert Object Datatype to String and vice versa in python

Tags: python

In Python How to convert Object Datatype to String and String Datatype to Object
I have a class called

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b=[]
        self.address=None
```

I created an object

```
nod=Node()
nod.b.append(Data)
nod.address=Node()
```

I want to convert `nod.address` to string for encryption and storing and after that decrypting the string convert string to Node class object

converting to string is simple `str(nod.address)`. I don't know how to convert string to the Node class object

```
# Node Class
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b=[]
        self.address=None
# Node Object
nod=Node()

# Converting Node Object to String
a=str(nod)

# Some encryption
a=a+str(fgwkuevbadfjqv)

# Description
a=a-str(fgwkuevbadfjqv)

# Accessing the Object
a.b.append(5)
a.address=cba,j
```

I don't know how to convert string to the Node object

```
# Accessing the Object
a.b.append(5)
a.address=cba,j
```

Error The string a has no parameter called b and address

Comment: It sounds like you want to learn about *serialization*.

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'b'

Comment: why do you need this ? did you look for a better way ?

Comment: The object looks something like  <__main__.Node object at 0x0000017AECE4D160>

Comment: I am designing a Blockchain application. For that, I need this. I want to use the address to calculate hash values. Thanks for responding

Comment: Ok I understand but from my point of vue it is bad to design it like that. why don't you add a property o hold the hash value? you don't need to convert an object to str to do a hashing on it and then return it to object. that does'nt make sense to me

Comment: I would not recommand somethings like eval('Node') because it is bad. your use case need some other Design than converting an obj to str and vice verca

Comment: Ok thanks, Can you suggest any other method. In this case, I want the address of the object dependent on the data present in it. So that when data is changed the address cannot be obtained.